# String array and Arraylist/list in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, can anybody provide me some sample program's for String array and Arraylist/list in C++

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer the following urls,

[1. String](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

[2. Character Sequence](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/)

[3. STL](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::vector<std::string>`. it can be accessed like a normal array (i.e. it provides `operator[]`). See here for the methods provided by [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/). You can insert the elements using [push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/) and access elements either using an `iterator` or `operator[]`

[3]:   [3]: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/operator%5B%5D/

[3]:   [3]: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/operator%5B%5D/